# Is there a specific term for "algebraic nullity"?

Tags: linear-algebra, article-writing

I want a compact way of saying "The algebraic multiplicity of $0$ for the operator $M$ is $2$".

Similar to the way "the nullity of M is $2$" means the geometric multiplicity of $0$ for the operator $M$ is $2$.

Comment: I would say "the multiplicity of $0$ for $M$ is $2$". This is also short and better than "nullity", which seems to refer to geometric multiplicity.

Comment: The nullity is the dimension of the kernel, which is also the geometric multiplicity of the 0th eigenvalue. But that's usually different from the algebraic multiplicity.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Therefore I would say "the multiplicity"  for the algebraic one instead of "nullity".